# c++ global hooking. Why SetWindowsHookEx return NULL?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I have a big problem with SetWindowsHookEx and WH_CALLWNDPROC! When use SetWindowsHookEx for local hook

```
HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), GetCurrentThreadId());
```

all work fine, but when i try set global hook or hook for other program:

```
HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), threadId);
```

where `threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, NULL);` 
and `HWND window = ::FindWindow(NULL,"Program title");`

i get NULL in hook...

I read very much for hooking but, i don't understand where is worng...
I have a headache for a few days.
Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: If you want to set up a global hook, your hook procedure must be in a dll, and you need to pass that dll's `HMODULE` to `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: To expand on IInspectable's comment, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx states "All global hook functions must be in libraries."

Comment: for the headache you should take Panadol and drink water :)

Comment: OK, i create dll file! But now i have problem with exporting on CallWndProc!
<code>hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("HookMessagesDll.dll")); 
hkprcSysMsg = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "CallWndProc"); </code>
hinstDLL i have result but in hkprcSysMsg i get NULL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

1. Put your CallWndProc function in a DLL
2. Export that function using a def file with the following content:

> LIBRARY
>
> ```
> EXPORTS
>
>     CallWndProc
> ```

1. Done!
2. (Try to always use GetLastError when a Win32 API Fails, and give the result when you ask something)